# Cneonction and nnCoection HTTP headers

Tags: http, interop, http-headers

We have often some issues in terms of interoperability on the Web. One of these issues for browsers vendors is the wrongly spelled `Connection` HTTP header. The most common errors are given by these two forms.

```
nnCoection:
Cneonction:
```

There are has been a few articles about this, including [Fun with HTTP headers](http://www.nextthing.org/archives/2005/08/07/fun-with-http-headers). Often it is happening by period, then disappear. It seems that some of them are created by load balancers such as [this example](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX108955): NetScaler Appliance.

Do you know any other instances of hardware or software that create these issues?

**Update** Here an example among others of a site which doesn't send back a good `Connection` HTTP header.

```
curl -sI ehg-nokiafin.hitbox.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 20:35:45 GMT
Server: Hitbox Gateway 9.3.6-rc1
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP LAW NID PSA ADM OUR IND NAV COM"
Cneonction: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, proxy-revalidate
Expires: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 20:35:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 23
```

**update 2011-01-26**

On Amazon forum about AWS, there is a [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=81954) about `nnCoection`. A comment says:

> FYI, the reason it misspells the word
>   connection is so that the internet
>   check-sum (a simple sum) still adds
>   up, this way the change can occur at
>   the packet level. If it completely
>   removed the header, it would have to
>   stall forwarding the response until
>   the header was entirely read, so it
>   could rewrite the headers, recompute
>   the checksum and then send it along.

with

```
sum(ord(c) for c in "Connection")
```

and

```
sum(ord(c) for c in "nnCoection")
```

both gives 1040

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure it's an actual *issue*?  The linked article suggests that these sorts of headers are "misspelled on purpose" so that a load balancer, reverse proxy or other middlebox can defeat the server's wishes that the connection be kept alive, without having to track a delta in TCP stream position over the life of the connection.  Something like this may actually be necessary to bring a downed and recovered server back into active duty, by forcing kept-alive connections to other servers to migrate to the one brought online.

If you have a protocol that's dependent on HTTP `Connection: keep-alive` to function ([cough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694135/eradicating-401-unauthorised-responses-followed-by-200-ok-responses/804919#804919)), you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: in the case of the load-balancer, there is a second connection header. but there are many cases where nothing else is sent. I will edit the post to give an example.

Comment: Looks good. I think these are misspelled by TCP load-balancers so that a) Clients will ignore them and b) They don't have to recalculate the checksum. This is a deliberate, although rather hackish way of doing it. I've seen it before in other cases.

Comment: @MarkR Good point about the checksum.  Both misspellings result from swapping adjacent 16-bit words, and which one is used is likely dependent on whether the initial C falls on a word boundary; since TCP uses a ones-complement checksum of 16-bit words, exchanging two 16-bit words will not invalidate the checksum.  On the other hand, you probably won't see such shenanigans played with HTTPS.

Comment: It's totally OK not to add another Connection header if you don't need to.

Comment: Interesting, but gross.