# How come "Connection" is misspelled in HTTP response header?

Tags: http, curl, http-headers

We're running the following php code:

```php
function downloadwebsite($url, $nobody=false) {

$ch = curl_init();

// FLAGS
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $nobody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $nobody);

$content = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

return $content;
}


$website = downloadwebsite("www.imdb.com", true);
echo nl2br($website);
```

At one line in the response it says: "Cneonction: close".
Why is it misspelled? Is it on purpose?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798461/cneonction-and-nncoection-http-headers), it's done on purpose for load balancers.  It's done to help with keepalives, it seems.