# Getting 'Coikoe' in http request instead of 'Cookie'

Tags: http, cookies

Our website is receiving http requests from a user which contains '**Coikoe**' tag instead of '**Cookie**'.

Http request object received from firefox is mentioned below :

```
com.pratilipi.servlet.UxModeFilter doFilter: REQUEST : GET http://www.pratilipi.com/books/gujarati HTTP/1.1
Host: http//www.pratilipi.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: http://www.pratilipi.com/?action=login
Coikoe: _gat=1; visit_count=1; page_count=2
X-AppEngine-Country: XX
X-AppEngine-Region: xx
X-AppEngine-City: XXXXXX
X-AppEngine-CityLatLong: 12.232344,12.232445
```

Http request object received from google chrome is mentioned below :

```
com.pratilipi.servlet.UxModeFilter doFilter: REQUEST : GET http//www.pratilipi.com/books/hindi HTTP/1.1
Host: http//www.pratilipi.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http//www.pratilipi.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ta;q=0.6
Coikoe: _gat=1; visit_count=1; page_count=1
X-AppEngine-Country: XX
X-AppEngine-Region: xx
X-AppEngine-City: xxxxxx
X-AppEngine-CityLatLong: 12.232344,12.232445
```

User is using window 8 system.

Question : Why is this happening and how can I solve it? I have never seen anything like this before. Anyone has come accross anything like this

Thank You

Comment: Can confirm, seeing the same problem. As lost as you are.

Comment: @mrks, Can you give a few more details?

Comment: Might be a poorly written bot..

Comment: @TheChetan Honestly, I'm not sure what details might help here. I uploded the output of $_SERVER here: https://nopaste.me/view/9e9ca639

Comment: @MarinosAn That was my first thought, but since this was in our contact form and contained an actual, meaningful message complaining about access problems, I can rule this out.

Answer (score 6):

This user will be using some sort of privacy proxy.

The same happens for the `Connection` request header as explained in [Cneonction and nnCoection HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798461/cneonction-and-nncoection-http-headers): the proxy mangles the header so it won't be recognized by the receiver, but by merely shuffling some letters around the TCP packet's checksum will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna give a rather speculative answer based on some online research.

I went through all the specifications for [cookies](https://tools.ietf.org/id/cookie) right from the early drafts and there doesn't seem to be anything about `coikoe` or misspelling cookies.

---

I found another user (Pingu) who complained about the same on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Pingu/) about the same. His relevant tweets:

> ([1](https://twitter.com/Pingu/status/14380226863702016)) Weird problem: have a device that changes "Cookie" to "Coikoe" in TCP stream and don't know which it is. No deep packet inspection in place.
>
> ([2](https://twitter.com/Pingu/status/14379379874340864)) There is a Linksys Wifi Router, a Cisco Switch adding a VLAN-Tag and a Linux box routing the VLAN to Internet router. Nothing else. #Coikoe

I then asked him about it earlier today. [This](https://twitter.com/CheVaGiriShisht/status/907825603692437504) was his replay:

> It must have been something with my routing and iptables setup on the Linux box to allow the guests only limited access.
>
> I can remember the problem. But do not remember how I solved it. It happened from Clients connected to my Guest WiFi.

Given my understanding from your discussion in the comments earlier, I'm guessing that the router sends a `coikoe` header instead of a `cookie` if the user has limited connectivity and/or problems with the access point.

---

Also see [this ruby code](https://github.com/Alfo92/Proyecto2/blob/4b0bfbca7ef5c6cf224a93921334c87afdc16844/app/controllers/application_controller.rb) to see how they have handled the different cookie header:

```
 def set_cookie_header
   request.headers["HTTP_COOKIE"] ||= request.headers["HTTP_COIKOE"]
 end
```

---

I looked lots of other popular forums like reddit, 4chan, stackoverflow, facebook and google, but I could not get anything else. Goodluck with your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Well this is something like a typo mistake, just to confirm , use the following powershell command in the project directory

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "Coikoe" | group path | select name
```

and i hope you will be able to find the mistake you have made.