# 401 Unauthorized on ajax requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

We have recently moved our webserver to a new machine (IIS based) and in the asp.net mvc application I am working on, I have noticed that in the firebug console each request fails twice with a 401 error before finally succeeding on the 3rd try.  This did not happen previously and the application seems to be running slightly slower than before, though that could just be my perception.

What might be causing this issue and what might I be able to do in order to avoid it?

Comment: What type of authentication are you using for your application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/694135/406903

Comment: Was thinking something to do with HTTP Basic Authentication.  Think hmqcnoesy's link there is a good place to start though.

Comment: Its using Windows based authentication, which I believe is what we were using before also.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem couple weeks back and the below post saved my day...

https://serverfault.com/questions/137073/401-unauthorized-on-server-2008-r2-iis-7-5

I hope this may help you...

Comment: I don't think I'm having the same issue as I'm not using anonymous authentication and I dont have any Html.RenderAction() calls in my application.

Answer (score -2):

Consider trying to check your IIS pool. Or maybe a timeout expiration?

Comment: These are comments, not answers. Please provide suggestions *using comments on the question*.

Comment: This is the same by answering the post..It is a real solution but you can never know the best answer in software problems..

Comment: The point here I think is you are off the mark. These are just guesses or not specific enough - there may be instanced where a request in authorised because of the identity the app pool is running under. If that's what you mean you need to be specific.