# Can I see all responses in browser dev tools (Chrome/Edge) for authentication?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using mainly Chrome Dev Tools to evaluate page responsiveness but it seems that the default setup is missing useful insights.
The site uses NTLM and as per another post ([Eradicating 401 "Unauthorised" responses followed by 200 "Ok" responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694135/eradicating-401-unauthorised-responses-followed-by-200-ok-responses)), it generates two 401 responses and finally a 200 per page served. In dev tools however, I don't see this full chain, just the final 200 responses.

In other tools like Fiddler or JMeter, each request/response is captured.
I've looked into the settings and can't see anything to expand this information and I'm also unsure whether the response times factor in the two hidden 401 responses but it would be useful to show everything in dev tools if possible.
Thanks Dan

Comment: Do you have "Preserve log" enabled in the Network tab? And removed all filters? (Clear the filter search bar, select "All" request, etc.)

Comment: Hi Ivar - I have 'preserve log' ticked and no filters applied (ie types = ALL and all other options unticked). Under Settings -> Network I have 'preserve log' and 'record network log' ticked only. I'm running Chrome on Windows106.0.5249.119 for ref, although don't believe I have ever seen different behaviour.